# Why $x$ is not both , free and bound variable here?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I saw on math stack exchange and on other website that in the following statement
$4 ∈$ { $x ∈$ { $y:y$ is a prime } $: 13 -2x>1$ }
There is no free variable and, $x$ and $y$ are bound variables.

**My question:** Why there is no free variable? Because if we look at the statement $x ∈$ {$y:y$ is prime} here clearly $x$ is free variable so in the given statement $x$ should be both free and bound variable right?

Comment: Not very clear the syntax... with $x \in \{y : y \text { is prime} \}$ I suppose that you simply mean: "x is prime".

Comment: Basically, the set-builder operator $\{ x \mid \ldots \}$ binds the variable used (here is $x$). Thus, in $\{ y \mid y \text { is prime } \}$ $y$ is bound. And into $\{ x \mid x \text { is prime and } 13−2x > 1 \}$ $x$ is bound.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA That means in the statement $x \in \{y | y$ is prime $\}$ , $y$ is bound and $x$ is free. But in the set-builder operator ,that is writing as statement within set-builder form (in $x$) both $x$ and $y$ are bound. Am i thinking correct?

Comment: Yes....................

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank You i got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the proposition is rewritten (while preserving the use of $x$ and $y$) using only logical connectives, quantifiers, relations, functions, commas, parenthesis, etc., it would be
$$\exists z\exists w[\forall y(y\in w\leftrightarrow y\text{ is a prime})\land\forall x(x\in z\leftrightarrow x\in w\land 13-2x>1)\land 4\in z]$$
In the subformula $x\in z$, $x$ is not bound by any quantifier, so that a constant (or a term) can take its place. Hence $x$ is a free variable in the subformula. In the whole formula, however, $x$ is bounded by the quantifier "$\forall x$", so that a substitution of $x$ is not defined. Hence $x$ is not free in the whole proposition.